# Traerme los valores de la base de datos a través de un select - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

quiero traerme la información que corresponde con lo que selecciono desde un select.

**El Select**

```
<select class="custom-select mr-sm-12 wid" id="medidas">
    @foreach ($productos->medidas as $list)
      <option value ="{{ $list->product_id }}"> {{ $list->listado }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Aquí en el value paso la id del producto para compararlo con la tabla de productos.

Luego a través de AJAX hago la petición al servidor.

```
$('#medidas').on('change',function(){
           $value=$(this).val();
            $.ajax({                        
               type: "GET",                 
               url : '{{URL::to('medidas')}}',                    
               data:{'idproducto':$value},
               success: function(data)            
               {
                 $('#valorPrecio').html(data); 

                 console.log(data);       
               }
             });
        });
```

**Este es el controlador**

```
public function medidas(Request $request)
    {
        $productos = Medida::where('product_id', $request->idproducto)->get();
        return $productos;

    }
```

Bien en la tabla de medida tengo las distintas variaciones de los productos, medida, precio, precio antes. Vale pero como solo comparo la id, y en la tabla de medidas un producto puede tener más de una fila no se como compararla, además no se como extraer por ejemplo el campo precio y ponerlo en un `div` y otro campo como por ejemplo `pvpantes` y ponerlo en otro div.

Ahora mismo me trae todos los datos a través del console, pero si una id tiene dos filas por ejemplo, me trae las dos y claro el en el select es donde selecciono la medida que quiero que me traiga, no se si me explico.

**Edición, tengo esta solución para comparar**

Mando la medida que esta en el texto del select de este modo.

```
$medida=$('select[name="medidas"] option:selected').text();
```

Y luego lo comparo en el controlador:

```
public function medidas(Request $request)
    {
        $productos = Medida::where('product_id', $request->idproducto)->where('listado', $request->medida)->get();
        return $productos;
    }
```

Esto me trae en modo de objeto "creo" la fila que quiero sin problema, pero como accedo a esos datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno mi solución es así:

```
success: function(data)            
   {
     $('#valorPrecio').html(data.precio);                
     $('.pvpAntesFIN1').html(data.pvpAntes);
      //console.log(data);       
}
```

Lo que hace es imprimir el valor que trae por AJAX, en su respectivo `id` con `data.precio`.

Donde muestro el precio es aqui:

```
<h4 id="valorPrecio"> </h4><span>€</span>

@if ($productos->pvpAntes == null)
        
@else
  <div class="pvpAntesFIN1"></div>
 @endif
```

La cuestión es que si `pvpAntes` viene vacio no me imprime nada, pero si viene lleno me imprime el importe perfectamente, pero quiero añadirle el simbolo de €. Si lo añado dentro del `div` cuando me trae el valor me lo borra, y si lo pongo fuera siempre se ve, que puedeo hacer??

Y por otro lado, quiero que la petición AJAX se haga nada más entrar a la pagina para que siempre salga un valor.